# Java basic httpserver using apache httpcompoments

Tags: java, httpserver

I'm trying to unit test a really simple embedded http server in Java using apache httpcomponents and I think I'm doing something very wrong as it doesn´t work.

This is my server

```
public class Server {

  private static HttpServer server;

  public static void start() throws IOException {

    server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/page1", new PageHandler());
    server.start();
  }
}
```

And this is my test class

```
public class ServerTest {

  @Before
  public void initServer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("initServer");
    Server.start();
  }

  @Test
  public void testPage1_Ok() throws IOException {
    String url = "http://localhost:8000/page1";
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    httpclient.execute(httpget);
  }

}
```

The server requires authentication, so I would understand a 401 or similar (my server actually handles this), but I get this:

```
Jan 01, 2017 10:02:03 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8000: The target server failed to respond
```

and after a few tries I get a NoHttpResponseException

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8000 failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
```

Obviously, if I manually start the server and then try to get to http://localhost:8000/page1 manually it works

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: the start() method probably returns before the server is actually ready to handle requests, and you're thus sending requests too early.

Comment: I used a `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)` before sending the `httpclient.execute` and I got the same error